# IntegrityError: distinguish between unique constraint and not null violations

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psycopg2

I have this code:

```
try:
    principal = cls.objects.create(
        user_id=user.id,
        email=user.email,
        path='something'
    )
except IntegrityError:
    principal = cls.objects.get(
        user_id=user.id,
        email=user.email
    )
```

It tries to create a user with the given id and email, and if there already exists one - tries to get the existing record.

I know this is a bad construction and it will be refactored anyway. But my question is this:

How do i determine what kind of `IntegrityError` has happened: the one related to `unique` constraint violation (there is unique key on (user_id, email)) or the one related to `not null` constraint (`path` cannot be null)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

psycopg2 provides the `SQLSTATE` with the exception as the `pgcode` member, which gives you quite fine-grained error information to match on.

```
python3
>>> import psycopg2
>>> conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=regress")
>>> curs = conn.cursor()
>>> try:
...     curs.execute("INVALID;")
... except Exception as ex:
...     xx = ex
>>> xx.pgcode
'42601'
```

See [*Appendix A: Error Codes* in the PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html) for code meanings. Note that you can match coarsely on the first two chars for broad categories. In this case I can see that SQLSTATE 42601 is `syntax_error` in the `Syntax Error or Access Rule Violation` category.

The codes you want are:

```
23505   unique_violation
23502   not_null_violation
```

so you could write:

```
try:
    principal = cls.objects.create(
        user_id=user.id,
        email=user.email,
        path='something'
    )
except IntegrityError as ex:
    if ex.pgcode == '23505':
        principal = cls.objects.get(
            user_id=user.id,
            email=user.email
        )
    else:
        raise
```

That said, this is a bad way to do an `upsert` or `merge`. @pr0gg3d is presumably right in suggesting the right way to do it with Django; I don't do Django so I can't comment on that bit. For general info on upsert/merge see [depesz's article on the topic](http://www.depesz.com/2012/06/10/why-is-upsert-so-complicated/).

Answer (score 12):

Update as of 9-6-2017:

A pretty elegant way to do this is to `try`/`except IntegrityError as exc`, and then use some useful attributes on `exc.__cause__` and `exc.__cause__.diag` (a diagnostic class that gives you some other super relevant information on the error at hand - you can explore it yourself with `dir(exc.__cause__.diag)`).

The first one you can use was described above. To make your code more future proof you can reference the psycopg2 codes directly, and you can even check the constraint that was violated using the diagnostic class I mentioned above:

```
except IntegrityError as exc:
    from psycopg2 import errorcodes as pg_errorcodes
    assert exc.__cause__.pgcode == pg_errorcodes.UNIQUE_VIOLATION
    assert exc.__cause__.diag.constraint_name == 'tablename_colA_colB_unique_constraint'
```

edit for clarification: I have to use the `__cause__` accessor because I'm using Django, so to get to the psycopg2 IntegrityError class I have to call `exc.__cause__`

Comment: The error can also be accessed as `exc.orig` but I can't tell the difference with `__cause__`. Maybe this is addresses in you clarification edit but I don't understand it and I don't see the relation with Django.

Answer (score 3):

It could be better to use:

```
try:
    obj, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(user_id=user.id, email=user.email)
except IntegrityError:
    ....
```

as in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create

The `IntegrityError` should be raised only in the case there's a `NOT NULL` constraint violation.
Furthermore you can use `created` flag to know if the object already existed.

Comment: If anyone finds this: get_or_create() is cleaner but still not always atomic and suffers from race-conditions (depending on database configuration), as noted in the docs.

Comment: IntegrityError is raied for several errors, including Not Null and Unique constraint failures.