# How to get the record causing IntegrityError in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have the following in my django model, which I am using with PostgresSql

```
class Business(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,default="",unique=True)
```

In my view I have:

```
for b in bs: 
    try:
        p = Business(**b)
        p.save()
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

When the app is run and an IntegrityError is triggered I would like to grab the already inserted record and also the object (I assume 'p') that triggered the error and update the location field.

In pseudocode:

```
for b in bs: 
    try:
        p = Business(**b)
        p.save()
    except IntegrityError:

     EXISTING_RECORD.location = EXISTING_RECORD.location + p.location
     EXISTING_RECORD.save()
```

How is this done in django?

Comment: Is this your whole model or did you simplify to make the question easier?  Or more directly... is the only thing that can cause an integrity error if two businesses have the same name?

Comment: Hi Foon, this is simplified but name is the only unique key ( except for id ) - Bill

Answer (score 2):

This is the way I got the existing record that you are asking for.
In this case, I had MyModel with

```
unique_together = (("owner", "hsh"),)
```

I used regex to get the owner and hsh of the existing record that was causing the issue.

```
import re
from django.db import IntegrityError


try:
    // do something that might raise Integrity error

except IntegrityError as e:

    #example error message (e.message): 'duplicate key value violates unique constraint "thingi_userfile_owner_id_7031f4ac5e4595e3_uniq"\nDETAIL:  Key (owner_id, hsh)=(66819, 4252d2eba0e567e471cb08a8da4611e2) already exists.\n'

    import re
    match = re.search( r'Key \(owner_id, hsh\)=\((?P<owner_id>\d+), (?P<hsh>\w+)\) already', e.message)
    existing_record = MyModel.objects.get(owner_id=match.group('owner_id'), hsh=match.group('hsh'))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried get_or_create, but that doesn't quite work the way you want (if you do get_or_create with both the name and the location, you still get an integrity error; if you do what Joran suggested, unless you overload update, it will overwrite location as opposed to append.

This should work the way you want:

```
for b in bs: 
    bobj, new_flag = Business.objects.get_or_create(name=b['name'])
    if new_flag:
       bobj.location = b['location']
    else:
       bobj.location += b['location'] # or possibly something like += ',' + b['location'] if you wanted to separate them
    bobj.save()
```

It would be nice (and may be possible but I haven't tried), in the case where you can have multiple unique constraints, to be able to inspect the IntegrityException (similar to the accepted answer in [IntegrityError: distinguish between unique constraint and not null violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490172/integrityerror-distinguish-between-unique-constraint-and-not-null-violations?rq=1), which also has the downside of appearing to be postgres only) to determine which field(s) violated.  Note that if you wanted to follow your original framework, you can do `collidedObject = Business.objects.get(name=b['name'])` in your exception but that only works in the case where you know for sure that it was a name collision.

Answer (score -1):

```
for b in bs: 
    p = Business.objects.get_or_create(name=b['name'])
    p.update(**b)
    p.save()
```

I think anyway