# how to catch A 'UNIQUE constraint failed' 404 in django

Tags: python, django

How do I specifically catch a UNIQUE constraint failed 404 in the following code, I know I have to add something in the ( here? ) section

```
try:
    q = AnswerModel(user=user, yes_question=question_model)
    q.save()
except ( here? ):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/already_exists')
```

Comment: Have you tried *not* catching it so you know what it actually is?

Comment: errrrr of course, now i want to catch the unique constraint error so i can tell the user the already answered

Comment: Okay, so since you know what it is, put it in the `except` clause.

Comment: if you cant help me with what that except clause is, then why are you even bothering?

Comment: I tried helping you. You claimed that you already did what I said would tell you.

Comment: you told me to use the except, I don't know what the except clause is, but please i don't want to feel bad every time i ask a question, just let somebody else answer this

Comment: No, I told you to STOP using the `except`.

Comment: Run the code without try block (try: and except:) next check what exception django print as error and it will be what you need.

Comment: Give me a minute, I can answer this..

Answer (score 78, accepted):

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

except IntegrityError:
```

This is what you need.

**EDITED** for @mbrochh:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

except IntegrityError as e: 
    if 'unique constraint' in e.message: # or e.args[0] from Django 1.10
        #do something
```

Yes, you can be more precise but in question case `UNIQUE failed` is highly likely.

Comment: This is not sufficient because it catches more than just UNIQUE constraints.

Comment: That is still a bad solution because we don't know if those messages will ever change. Checking for the error code would be a better way.

Comment: That's the whole point of error codes! They are documented in the official Postgres docs and they will never change. Comparing something against a message string is incredibly bad practice.

Comment: They can change error code in Postgres. But OK it will be less probable.

Comment: As of django 1.10 IntegrityError has no attribute message

Comment: As of Django 1.10, you need to use: `if 'unique constraint' in e.args[0]`

Comment: if 'UNIQUE constraint failed' in e.args[0]

Comment: Django translates the content of the `args` field if the installation language is different, and therefore breaks this trick.

Comment: Django 3.1 this worked for me --> if 'unique constraint'.lower() in str(err).lower(): #do something

Comment: for future support, I prefer 'unique constraint' in str(e.args).lower()

Comment: The problem is when I changed my database backend. Sqlite's error message contains `unique constraint` but MariaDB's message is `Duplicate entry 'THE_SAME_CODE' for key 'address_countries.code'`. Any idea how to catch not unique constraints?

Answer (score 27):

IMHO, I would recommend to resolve this situation by get_or_create().

```
new_obj, created = AnswerModel.objects.get_or_create(user=user, yes_question=question_model)
if created:
    do_something_for_new_object(new_obj)
else:
    logging.error("Duplicated item.")
    return
```

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: this was working for me until I tried it with a new database and now I am still getting the  error again: `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed`

Comment: This will not work in case where two concurrent requests hit this code at the same time.

Comment: @nickswiss It'll work.  According to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), `get_or_create` is atomic if the arguments have a uniqueness constraint.

Answer (score 10):

Usually the "ask for forgiveness" principle is a good practice in programming but in this special case, I would not recommend it.

The exception you are looking for is `IntegrityError`. You could have easily figured that out yourself by simply removing the try-catch block and forcing that exception. The traceback shows the exception class.

The problem is, there are several different kinds of integrity errors, so inside your try-catch block you would have to check for something like `if ex.pgcode == 23505` to see if this is actually a UNIQUE constraint error. This has been answered before here: [IntegrityError: distinguish between unique constraint and not null violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490172/integrityerror-distinguish-between-unique-constraint-and-not-null-violations)

It gets worse: Each ORM has different error codes, the field name will not be `pgcode` but something else and some ORMs don't throw UNIQUE constraints at all. So if you are building a reusable app or if you are using a ORM that sucks (such as MySQL) or if you are not sure if you will change the database of your project at some time in the future, you should not do this!

The better way is simply removing the try-catch block and check if the object is already in the database before saving.

I don't know which field is UNIQUE in your case, so I will just assume that it is the `user` field. Your code would look something like this:

```
answers = AnswerModel.objects.filter(user=user)
if answers:
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/already_exists')
obj = AnswerModel.objects.create(user=user, yes_question=question_model)
...
```

If you are dealing with a combined unique constraint, the first line would be this:

```
answers = AnswerModel.objects.filter(user=user, yes_question=question_model)
```

Comment: EAFP is only a good practice in python, not programming itself. Many languages, like C++, use EAFP only when absolutely necessary and otherwise prefer LBYL.

Comment: You're using the term "ORM" to refer to database management systems. I suggest replacing it with the acronym "DBMS".

Answer (score 4):

**For Python > 3.5**

You need:

```
except IntegrityError as e: 
   if 'unique constraint' in str(e.args).lower():
```

Example:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

 for column in csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=',', quotechar="|"):
     try:
         _, created = Brand.objects.update_or_create(
            system_id=column[0],
            name=column[1],
            slug=column[2],
            description=column[3],
            image=column[4]
           )
     except IntegrityError as e: 
           if 'unique constraint' in str(e.args).lower():
               continue 
           else:
               raise e # Not the unique error we were expecting
```

Comment: e.args is a list in my case so need: if 'unique constraint' in str(e.args) instead

Comment: Also error message is "UNIQUE constraint failed" as per Django 4 at least

Comment: @Ryan that is why there is a .lower() function call, to capture it in any version of Django.

Comment: @OmarGonzales I added the .lower() to your orig code when I edited. Put comment in first then thought I can edit to fix.

Answer (score 2):

Found in `django.db.models.query.QuerySet._create_object_from_params`. And with some change:

```
from typing import Any, Dict, Type  
from django.db import transaction, IntegrityError, Model


def get_or_create_obj(model: Type[Model], defaults: Dict[str, Any] = None, **kwargs: Any):
    defaults = defaults or {}
    try:
        with transaction.atomic():
            return model.objects.create(**kwargs, **defaults), True
    except IntegrityError as e:
        try:
            return model.objects.using("default").get(**kwargs), False
        except model.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        raise e
```

Answer (score 1):

Unique constraint fail return :"('UNIQUE constraint failed: notepad_notepadform.title')" which is basically a tuple,So we can use below code to catch it and do whatever required:

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
try:
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    except IntegrityError as e:
        if 'UNIQUE constraint' in str(e.args):
            #your code here
```

Answer (score 1):

After a brief search, I see that this is a problem, and hopefully, it will be addressed by the Django team. See: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/34610

I have a workaround and it involves the use of the `save` method of `Model`.
First I wanted to use the `clean` method however somehow it did not work. Bu `save` is good enough.

### Problem

Django raises an `IntegrityError` and redirects the error message of the database management system when a unique constraint happens. However, an `IntegrityError` can be risen for other errors too. So one needs to check the message of the error to see if the error is due to a unique constraint.

But different database management systems use different messages for unique constraints such as:

- Sqlite: `Error while executing SQL query on database '[The databse]': UNIQUE constraint failed: [The field]`
- MariaDB: `SQL Error (1062): Duplicate entry '[The value]' for key '[The field]'`

as you see finding a pattern for some common text looks like a challenge.

### Solution

Override the `save` method of the `Model` and check if any other entry already exist on save.

Please notice `save` can be invoked when one creates a new entry or updates an entry.

Here I have a `Countries` model that would save list of available countries.

```
class Countries(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_created=True, auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False, unique=True)
    timezone = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=False, blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(
            self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None
    ):
        # To check unique constraint.

        try:
            country_with_the_same_code = Countries.objects.get(code=self.code)
            # Get a country that has the code (must be unique)
            # If there is no such country, DoesNotExist exception will be risen,
            # and the next lines will be skipped.

            # Check if self.pk is not equal to the existing country's pk with the
            # same code
            # If it is not equal, It means someone is trying to create a new country
            # or update a country, and the code is equal to some other entries code.
            # (Raise an error)

            # if it is equal, it means someone is trying to update a country with the same
            # code of itself. (No error)
            if self.pk != country_with_the_same_code.pk:
                raise ValidationError("Unique Constraint failed for code")
        except Countries.DoesNotExist:
            # If no country is available with the same code (must be unique)
            # do nothing
            pass

        # Just execute save method of super.
        super(Countries, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update, using=using,
                                    update_fields=update_fields)
```

I over-commented the `save` method, just because I am lazy to explain it here...

And here how one can use it:

```
try:
    the_country = Countries(name=name, code=code, timezone=timezone)
    the_country.save()
except ValidationError as e:
        if "Unique Constraint failed" in str(e):
            print("Not unique")
```

### Update

Creating a custom Exception such as `Unique` instead of `ValidationError` would be a better approach. That way you do not need to check the message and the usage would change to be as such:

```
try:
    the_country = Countries(name=name, code=code, timezone=timezone)
    the_country.save()
except Unique:
        print("Not unique")
```