# Django Models: How to retrieve custom error messages in view function?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        db_table = 't_user_profile'

    display_name = models.CharField(
        max_length=20,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': ("A user with that display name already exists."),
        },
        blank=True
    )
```

I have a view function:

```
@csrf_exempt
def change_display_name(request):

    data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
    display_name = data.get('displayName')

    try:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(id=2)

    except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'User does not exist.'}, safe=False)

    user_profile.display_name = display_name
    user_profile.save()

    return JsonResponse({'status': 'SUCCESS'}, safe=False)
```

How do I try except the unique display_name and return in JSON the custom error message I setup in my model?

Comment: as `display_name` is your only input of user_profile model, you can catch integrity error send your response.

Comment: You should use a form for this. Or, since you're dealing with JSON, you should use Django REST Framework and its serializers to manage the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Do You want to handle `UNIQUE` `intergrityError`? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729487/how-do-catch-a-unique-constraint-failed-404-in-django)

Answer (score 0):

You need to run validation before saving. Here is an example based on the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.full_clean):

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

user_profile.display_name = display_name

try:
    user_profile.full_clean()
except ValidationError as e:
    # Do something based on the errors contained in e.message_dict.
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Some error message.'}, safe=False)

user_profile.save()
```

If, for some reason, you don't want to do full validation, you can check just the uniqueness constraints with `user_profile.validate_unique()` instead of `full_clean()`. Read more [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.validate_unique).