How to localize Django duplicate key value violates unique constraint error message?
Problem description
I would want to provide clear localized error messages to client using Django.
I have the following unique field:
class Foo(models.Model)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, default=None, blank=True,
                              null=True, verbose_name=gettext_lazy('email address'), error_messages={'unique': gettext_lazy("Email address is already registered to another user.")})

When I try to save duplicate email address, I still get an error
psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "foo_email_key"

Question
Why is my error message not localized? How can be the desired behaviour obtained?

Is your purpose for the localization for the things shown to users or do you actually want the site admins, maintainers to also get translated logs / errors?? Because normal users won't be able to see the error you've mentioned there, they'll get a different message which is more user friendly (And actually supports localization).

@AbdulAzizBarkat how can I pass more friendly error message to users?  So that the message is specific to these situations. Currently actually this messy message is passed from the API to end user?

The error page you're looking at won't be shown to users (If you're looking at an error page). That error page only shows up when DEBUG=True and when your app is live you should have that set to False.

@AbdulAzizBarkat I use my Django app just as API, my views are implemented with React. So basically I could just pass error messages directly to end user, or wrap my save() method with try, except and generate user friendly Exception. So could I somehow just catch these specific cases in except statement? Or is there some other way to obtain the desired outcome?

This could be one solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729487/how-to-catch-a-unique-constraint-failed-404-in-django
