# Getting information about integrity constraint violation error without parsing error message

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm using SQLAlchemy + psycopg2 to build an API exposing a DB.

I'd like to produce a useful error message in case of unique or foreign key constraint violation. Like the name of the field(s) involved in the error.

AFAIU, I should be able to get the constraint name from PostgreSQL. This would leave me the job of getting the fields from the constraint name. The part I'm focusing on right now is getting that constraint name.

I catch `sqla.exc.IntegrityError`, then access the underlying psycopg2 exception via the `orig` attribute. It may be a `psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation` or a `psycopg2.errors.ForeignKeyViolation`, for instance.

I don't know how to get to the extra information about the error.

[This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/130121/226938) points to [this PostgreSQL doc page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-EXCEPTION-DIAGNOSTICS) which involves SQL statements.

Is there a way to let psycopg2 do that for me and add this extra information to the exception?

Is there another way to get the information?

Do I need to access some error message and parse it?

---

**Edit**:

Thanks to [@Ian Wilson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69148696/4653485), I came up with this (following example only details unique constraint violation):

```py
if isinstance(exc, sqla.exc.IntegrityError):
    if isinstance(exc.orig, ppe.UniqueViolation):
        # Get table and constraint name from diag info
        table_name = exc.orig.diag.table_name
        constraint_name = exc.orig.diag.constraint_name
        # Inspect DB to get constraint object
        inspector = sqla.inspect(db_engine)
        unique_constraints = inspector.get_unique_constraints(table_name)
        constraint = next(
            c for c in unique_constraints
            if c['name'] == constraint_name
        )
        # Get column names from object
        column_names = constraint['column_names']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the constraint name via `e.__cause__.diag.constraint_name`.  I had never heard of it but found a related question I linked that seems to provide the information you need.

[IntegrityError: distinguish between unique constraint and not null violations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12490172/integrityerror-distinguish-between-unique-constraint-and-not-null-violations)

Just wanted to also add that I've had issues with implicit constraint names while using alembic before so you might need to set conventions if that comes up.  I think that was mostly related to reflecting back from the db but implicit names might make it hard to find the related columns.

[configuring-constraint-naming-conventions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#configuring-constraint-naming-conventions)

Comment: Spot on! Thanks. `diag` is what I was after, I just couldn't find it searching the internet. I did see that question but somehow missed that part of that answer. I use `orig` to access the underlying psycopg2 exception. I can't tell the difference with `__cause__`. I looked in the code and none seems to be deprecated in favor of the other.

Comment: Also thanks for the interesting comment about constraint names. Finally I didn't need it (see my question edit) but I'll keep it in mind when thinking about migrations.